# React Component css in JS

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new at react and I can understand the difference between `React.Component` and a function.

In these two pictures I have the same HTML and the same CSS but my CSS is done in the javascript file. When I use the CSS in a function, it works, but in a react component it does not.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

**Component**

```js
render() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div style={section}>
      <div style={container}>
        <div>
           <div style={title}>
             <h1>TEste</h1>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Function**

```js
const classes = useStyles();

return (
  <div className={classes.section}>
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div>
        <div className={classes.title}>
          <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Check the class component. Replace `style={section}` with `className={classes.section}` etc as you did in the functional component.

Comment: Please paste your code instead of attaching screenshots, as is specified in the manual - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Hangindev the component is incorrect don’t load my css properly the function is correct